# Macbook Pro Mid 2015 booting to a black screen

Tags: macbook-pro, startup, hardware

I am using a [Macbook Pro 15 inch Mid 2015](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-i7-2.5-15-dual-graphics-mid-2015-retina-display-specs.html). Running MacOS Catalina. I believe it is most up to date as of 11/7/2019, but I am unable to check.

Issues started a few days ago when my machine started looping while booting to a screen that said:

> "You need to restart your computer. Hold down the Power button for
>   several seconds or press the Restart button."

[This webpage](https://macpaw.com/how-to/fix-kernel-panic-on-macos) suggested that I boot into Safe mode; which worked! The computer booted just fine.

A day or so later, I no longer get any graphical response when booting normally, or into safe mode. The computer makes the boot sound, and after a few seconds the fans start spinning audibly. I've tried each solution from [here](http://osxdaily.com/2014/11/22/fix-macbook-pro-booting-black-screen/) (Except the last one because I don't know how to do that with a black screen) with no luck.

**I'm hoping someone has further insight to why this is occurring and how to fix it.**

I had a very similar issue with my old Macbook pro from 2011. The fact that my current model would need to have 2 graphics cards fail to brick the machine influenced my original purchase... I would really hate to see this one die at the same age as my old one.

Update: Went to an "Official Apple Service Provider" and they nicely let me know for $70 that there is a problem with my logic board and it needs to be replaced for $750. It was nice how specific they were about the problem.